# Command to validate between current day and 7 day old in bash scriptlinux

Tags: linux, bash

I want to validate, the date given as input is 7 day old or more from current day in bash script linux

Comment: @Samuel : Don't you think that this depends on the syntax where the day is specified in the input? For instance, I would write todays date as `15. September 2021`, while my friend would write it as `２０２１年9月15日`. Do you want to validate all possible date formats?

Answer (score 0):

This command provides the date 7 days previous to now, in seconds (since 1/1/1970):
`minus7=$(date -d "7 days ago" "+%s")`
This command provides the date in seconds of the user's input date:
`tstDate=$(date -d "$yourInputDate" "+%s")`
then
`let delta=$tstDate-$minus7`